# Google Cloud API Request error Violation in CreateServiceRequest.service_id

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

i implemented a test postman request to create a service on Google cloud run using API.
I have some a problem with payload into POST request.
This my Payload JSON:

```
{
    "name": "",
    "description": "Scrape Data",
    "uid": "e17a0f0c-c8d0-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002",
    "generation": "1",
    "labels": {
        "cloud.googleapis.com/location": "us-central1"
      },
      "annotations": {
        "run.googleapis.com/client-name": "Cloud Code for VS Code",
        "serving.knative.dev/creator": "<name_account>@gmail.com",
        "client.knative.dev/user-image": "gcr.io/${project_id}/job-ondemand",
        "run.googleapis.com/client-version": "1.21.2",
        "run.googleapis.com/operation-id": "682aea1c-c8d1-11ed-afa1-0242ac120002",
        "run.googleapis.com/ingress": "all",
        "run.googleapis.com/ingress-status": "all"
      },
       "createTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z",
       "updateTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z",
       "deleteTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z",
       "expireTime": "2030-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z",
       "creator": "<name_account>@gmail.com",
       "lastModifier": "",
       "client": "Cloud Code for VS Code",
       "clientVersion": "1.21.2",
       "ingress": "INGRESS_TRAFFIC_ALL",
       "launchStage": "ALPHA",
       "binaryAuthorization": {
           "breakglassJustification": "",
           "useDefault": "false"
        },
        "template": {
            "revision": "scrape-00001-f1",
            "labels": {

            },
            "scaling": {
                "minInstanceCount": 1,
                "maxInstanceCount": 10
            },
            "timeout": "300s",
            "serviceAccount": "<account>",
            "containers": [
                {
                    "name": "scrape",
                    "image": "gcr.io/${project_id}/job-ondemand",
                    "env": [
                        {
                            "name": "TEXT",
                            "value": "AAAAAAA"
                        }
                    ],
                    "resources": {
                        "limits": {
                            "cpu": "1",
                            "memory": "256Mi"
                          }
                      },
                      "ports": [
                        {
                            "name": " http1",
                            "containerPort": "8080"
                        }
                    ]
                }
                
              ]
          },
          "traffic": [
              {
                "type": "TRAFFIC_TARGET_ALLOCATION_TYPE_UNSPECIFIED",
                "percent": 100
              }
          ],
          "observedGeneration": "1",
          "conditions": [
              {
                "type": "Ready",
                "state": "STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
                "lastTransitionTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z"
              },
              {
                "type": "ConfigurationsReady",
                "state": "STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
                "lastTransitionTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z"
              },
              {
                "type": "RoutesReady",
                "state": "STATE_UNSPECIFIED",
                "lastTransitionTime": "2014-10-02T15:01:23.045123456Z"
              }
          ],
          "latestReadyRevision": "scrape-00001ing",
          "latestCreatedRevision": "scrape-00001"
}
```

and i receive this error when i run request:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Violation in CreateServiceRequest.service_id: only lowercase, digits, and hyphens; must begin with letter, and cannot end with hyphen; must be less than 50 characters.",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
                "fieldViolations": [
                    {
                        "field": "Violation in CreateServiceRequest.service_id",
                        "description": "only lowercase, digits, and hyphens; must begin with letter, and cannot end with hyphen; must be less than 50 characters."
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

But i my payload i don't have the service_id, i have seen in the documentation but i don't found this parameter.

Thank

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all,
i have fix it. The versionId is a secondary parameter to set into url.

Comment: Hi @dev_, I hit this error while using Terraform. Do you have any more details on what the actual problem was?